# php shell scripting for FFmpeg video conversion

Tags: shell, scripting, ffmpeg, php

I have a shell script for converting any video into mp4 format(using ffmpeg) . I want to write a php script for executing ffmpeg to convert any video format into mp4 video format .

Here is the shell script : http://pastebin.com/PH3QWFqQ

Shell script running good without shell_exec() .
Update:

I have tried doing it by using shell_exec() but i am getting an error :

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in test1.php on line 33

UPDATE:

I have tried with shell_exec() : 
  It executes but not showing any output . But the .sh file alone shows output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be using `shell_exec`, but you really need to make sure that no user inputs get directly into the command. You really don't want your users to execute commands on your servers shell.
Example: `shell_exec("ffmpeg ...");`

If you don't want to use `shell_exec`, just google "ffmpeg php", there are some ffmpeg extensions for PHP. I found this one, for example: http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

You can execute external tools with exec or system.